# Function that takes an iterator of generic type T, and returns an iterator that only gives Ts that are within a certain radius of a point

Tags: rust

I want to write a function that takes an iterator of generic type `T`, and returns an iterator that only gives `T`s that are within a certain radius of a point. Because traits cannot contain associated fields, and I do not want to implement `GetX` and `GetY` for every `T`, I instead will also pass in a function that will retrieve the `x` and `y` position of every `T`.

I realize that this isn't the most efficient spatial partitioning / broad phase collision detection algorithm, but I just want to prove to myself that a function with this signature can exist within the borrow checking rules.

If this function signature is impossible to implement, how can I modify it to make it work, with the fewest constraints/bounds on `T` and `impl Iterator`?

Here is my attempt:

```
pub fn filter<'a, T>(
    world: impl Iterator<Item = &'a T>,
    positions: fn(&'a T) -> (f32, f32),
    near_to: (f32, f32),
    radius: f32,
) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a T> {
    //We cannot access a field of the geneic item "T" directly, so we instead pass a function that retrieves that field from each "T".
    let positions = world.map(positions).collect::<Vec<(f32, f32)>>();
    //filter the world by the distance from the near_to point
    let filter = world.enumerate().filter(move |(i, _entity)| {
        //get the x,y pposition of the current entity
        let (x, y) = positions[*i];
        //how far is it from the near_to point?
        let (dx, dy) = (x - near_to.0, y - near_to.1);
        //is it within the radius?
        dx * dx + dy * dy < radius * radius
    });
    //we don't want the index, just the entity
    filter.map(|(_, entity)| entity)
}
```

The error is:

```
1   | pub fn filter<'a, T>(world: impl Iterator<Item = &'a T>, positions: fn(&'a T) -> (f32, f32), near_to: (f32, f32), radius: f32) -> impl Iter... 
    |                      ----- move occurs because `world` has type `impl Iterator<Item = &'a T>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait       
2   |     let positions = world.map(positions).collect::<Vec<(f32,f32)>>();
    |                           -------------- `world` moved due to this method call
3   |     let filter = world.enumerate().filter(move |(i, _entity)| {
    |                  ^^^^^ value used here after move
    |
note: `map` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `world`
   --> D:\rust\.rustup\toolchains\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\core\src\iter\traits\iterator.rs:800:18
    |
800 |     fn map<B, F>(self, f: F) -> Map<Self, F>
    |                  ^^^^
help: consider further restricting this bound
    |
1   | pub fn filter<'a, T>(world: impl Iterator<Item = &'a T> + Copy, positions: fn(&'a T) -> (f32, f32), near_to: (f32, f32), radius: f32) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a T> {
    |                                                         ++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
```

Comment: I am more than skeptical about the reasons that lead you not to put the `positions` function inside a trait, and use the type system to implicitly pass the `positions` function as an argument for you, rather than doing what you are doing. Because, in the end, no matter the solution, you *will* write a getter function for every `T` for which you call this function.

Answer (score 5):

Since this operation only filters elements from `world` without respect to other elements, this can be done using `.filter()` only:

```
pub fn filter<'a, T>(
    world: impl Iterator<Item = &'a T>,
    positions: fn(&'a T) -> (f32, f32),
    near_to: (f32, f32),
    radius: f32,
) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a T> {
    world.filter(move |entity| {
        let (x, y) = positions(entity);
        let (dx, dy) = (x - near_to.0, y - near_to.1);
        dx * dx + dy * dy < radius * radius
    })
}
```